# Exim, virtualhost support but with wildcard sub-domains

Tags: linux, exim

I successfully setup Exim with virtualhost support. But I have a problem right now.

I have three domains:

aaa.com
bbb.com
ccc.com

Exim successfully retrieves emails to these domains and then forwards them to appropriate email addresses set in vhost files for each domain.

But for bbb.com, I have hundreds of sub-domains such as 111.bbb.com, 222.bbb.com, 333.bbb.com

The problem is, how can I set Exim to capture emails coming to all these sub-domains of bbb.com based on the vhost file set for bbb.com?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This depends upon how you set up Exim to handle the lookup; we'd need to see the Router to give a definitive answer.

If you used `lsearch`, then `partial()lsearch` as a lookup type instead is probably what you want.  See the section "Partial matching in single-key lookups" of The Exim Specification (`spec.txt` in the distribution, online on the Exim website too, also PDF, PS, etc).